# How do I filter entities by date range in odata4j?

Tags: java, odata, odata4j

The odata4j [AppEngineConsumerExample](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse/tags/0.2/odata4j-core/test/org/odata4j/examples/consumer/AppEngineConsumerExample.java) demonstrates how to filter entities on string and numeric values with code similar to the following:

```
reportEntity("\nNon-discontinued product with reorderLevel > 25 (two filter predicates): " , 
            c.getEntities("Product")
            .filter("reorderLevel gt 25 and discontinued eq false")
            .top(1)
            .execute().first());
```

I'm fairly new to Java (my background is .NET/C#), but the above makes sense.  However, I'm unsure how to do something similar for dates.  The dates coming from my WCF OData service are formatted as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a function of OData itself rather than odata4j.  The string passed to the filter function in odata4j is the same expression that would be passed via a URL.  I found tons of filter examples on the [Netflix OData Catalog page](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/OData_Catalog).

To filter dates, use something like this:

```
reportEntity("\nProduct with order date greater than March 1, 2010: " , 
        c.getEntities("Product")
        .filter("OrderDate gt datetime'2010-03-01'")
        .top(1)
        .execute().first());
```

Comment: Glad to hear you got this working.  Seems like a a syntax for providing literal parameters would have been useful here.  Or a query builder api.  What do you think?